# ruby - pipe-in from one class to another

Tags: ruby, pipe

i have a class named `Foo`, which uses pipe-in to read input from the command line, and it works well. i have another class named `Bar`, which invokes `Foo`, and has to feed (pipe-in) `Foo` in the same manner that `Foo` expects, but it does not seem to work for me.

see my snippet below.
i would appreciate any help.

**note:**
i know i can avoid doing so by passing object data from `Bar` to `Foo`, but i would like to use the pipes.

```
$ ls -x1
bar.rb
foo.rb
test.rb

$ cat *
# bar.rb
require "stringio"
class Bar
  def self.pipe
    input = StringIO.new
    input.write "bar"
    input.rewind
    $stdin = input
    Foo.print
    $stdin = STDIN
  end
end

# foo.rb
class Foo
  @@stdin = STDIN.tty? ? nil : $stdin.read #ok for cli pipe-in
  
  def self.print
    puts "stdin: #{@@stdin}"
  end
end

# test.rb
$:.unshift File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__))
require "foo"
require "bar"
Bar.pipe

$ echo "piped" | ruby test.rb 
stdin: piped

$ ruby test.rb 
stdin:
```

what is being done wrong, and why? a solution would be great.

Answer (score 1):

i found my error. i modifying `Foo` as follow, but i broke its functionality.

```
$ cat foo.rb 
# foo.rb
class Foo
  def self.print
    @@stdin = STDIN.tty? ? nil : $stdin.read #ok for cli pipe-in
    puts "stdin: #{@@stdin}"
  end
end

$ echo "piped" | ruby test.rb 
stdin: bar
```